# Attempting to read txt file as a csv but running into issues

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am attempting to read a txt file as a csv that id formatted as below:

```
Text    value1  Value2
Text    value1
Text    value1
Text    value1
Text    value1
Text    value1  Value2
Text    value1  Value2
Text    value1  Value2
Text    value1  Value2
Text    value1  Value2
```

I have tried the following line:

```py
contents = pd.read_csv(pathtemp2,delimiter='\t',header = None,dtype="string")
```

but get back the following error:

````
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try with column names and space as seperator:

```py
content = pd.read_csv(pathtemp2, sep=" ", header=None, names=["col1", "col2", "col3"])
```

or try [read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
contents = pd.read_fwf(pathtemp2)
```

Comment: using pd.read_fwf worked except it doesn't recognize the tab delimiter and gives me only 1 column

Comment: Share actual data, first few rows will help

Comment: Time and Date Jun/30/2020 05:58:10
Program No. 0
Trigger No. 15
TIME[ms] 292
Total Status NG
Tool01:Measurement OK 82
Tool02:Measurement OK 79

Comment: Theres the first few lines of the data im trying to read i need 2 columns for each type split by tab

Comment: When I asked for actual data, I meant adding it to your post. Adding to comment made in unformatted. Take a look at his [link](https://repl.it/repls/PastFluffyProgramminglanguages). It has both code and the sample data you had in initial post description. It can create the expected dataframe, worth to mention `pandas` version is `1.0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you need to open the file.

From:

```
contents = pd.read_csv(pathtemp2,delimiter='\t',header = None,dtype="string")
```

To:

```
contents = pd.read_csv(open(pathtemp2),delimiter='\t',header = None,dtype="string")
```

Comment: I do not get the error anymore but i end up with an empty data frame when i try this